# FontAwesome icon with a circle

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to create fontawesome icons within a circle and I have used border css for the same to achieve. However, for different font icons, the border is not circular, it changes it's shape for some of the icons like facebook.

I have following code snippet, in which facebook border isn't circular. Can you kindly let me know how to achieve circular (exact circle) border for all icons, irrespective of their sizes (event twitter and server icons aren't looking like uniform circles)?

https://jsfiddle.net/1d7fvLy5/1/

```
i.fa {
  margin: 0.5em;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #303030;
  border: 2px solid #303030;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

i.fa:hover{
  color:lightblue;
   border: 2px solid lightblue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `width: 1em;` and `text-align: center;` to `i.fa` should work.

Comment: After trying for a while, this really looked like magic when it worked. :) Thank you Richard. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you can use fontAwesome's stacking icons feature, like this:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1d7fvLy5/2/

And here's the examples page for fontAwesome http://fontawesome.io/examples

Comment: Thanks for sharing about stacking. I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Don't forget the `fa-fw` class. I don't know if Fontawesome 5 still uses it, but, it sets a fixed width on the icons.

Answer (score 0):

To make a perfect circle, you only need to have a square and not a rectangle.

This means that your height must be equal to your width.

Try this class :

```
i.fa {
  margin: 0.5em;
  font-size: 4em;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #303030;
  border: 2px solid #303030;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

HTML

```
<a class="align-items-center justify-content-center border d-flex roundbutton shadow text-decoration-none" href="#">
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #4267b2"></i>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
    .roundbutton {
    display: block;
    height: 4vw;
    width: 4vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;

}

.socialSignInBtns:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270359/circle-outline-for-fontawesome-icons-in-react-native