# circle outline for fontAwesome icons in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to use the fontAwesome + icon such that it is in the middle of a circle. I want to use it as one icon item. I read that we can use it along with the circle icon and place it inside that but I couldn't make it work.

```
import IconFA from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

        <IconFA
         name="plus"
         size={moderateScale(30)}
         color="black"
         style={styles.thumbnail}
         />
        {/* <IconFA
        name="circle-thin"
        size={moderateScale(67)}
        color="white"
      /> */}

  thumbnail: {
    height: 68,
    width: 68,
    position: 'relative',
  },
```

Alternatively, I read about 'stacked' font awesome icons but couldn't understand how to use it in react native.

Reference: https://jsfiddle.net/1d7fvLy5/1/

Snack Expo:

https://snack.expo.io/9Ild0Q1zG

I want to make something like this:

[image]

I am also open to using a `<Thumbnail>` if I find a similar icon's link but I couldn't find any such free icon online.

Comment: In your reference example the circle isn't actually an icon.  It's a css border with a border-radius to make it circular.  Does that distinction matter to you?

Comment: to complete previous comment, try `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  thumbnail: {
    height: 68,
    width: 68,
    position: 'relative',
    border: '1px solid',
    borderRadius:'50%',
    display:'inline-flex',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
}` for your styles.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus This doesn't work for react native since border isn't a style property in stylesheets. Also, inline-flex can't be used. But otherwise, yeah, I don't mind using plain css for this too.

Comment: oups, i trusted : https://snack.expo.io/qz_1J!ZGR looked like working fine ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSFiddle example that you posted creates the circle using a CSS border with `border-radius` to make it circular.  We can do pretty much the same thing in react-native, though `borderRadius` in react-native can only be a fixed number and not a percent (edit: this limitation is specific to typescript since the `borderRadius` property has type `number`.  Percentage strings do work at runtime).

You can tweak this code however you want, but this will get the job done.  You can use `IconFA` and `CircleBorder` as two separate nested components but I also made a component `IconInCircle` which combines the two.

```
const IconInCircle = ({ circleSize, borderWidth = 2, borderColor = 'black', ...props}) => (
  <CircleBorder
    size={circleSize}
    borderWidth={borderWidth}
    borderColor={borderColor}
  >
    <IconFA {...props} />
  </CircleBorder>
);

const CircleBorder = ({ size, borderWidth, borderColor, children }) => (
  <View
    style={{
      width: size,
      height: size,
      borderRadius: 0.5 * size,
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderColor,
      borderWidth,
    }}>
    {children}
  </View>
);
```

The `IconInCircle` component takes three props specific to the border: `circleSize`, `borderWidth`, and `borderColor`.  All other props are passed through into the `IconFA` child component.

Basically what we are doing is placing the icon inside of a fixed-size `View` with a circular border and centered contents.

Now we can use it like so:

```
      <IconInCircle
        name="plus"
        size={30}
        color="black"
        style={styles.thumbnail}
        borderWidth={1}
        circleSize={50}
      />
```

[Expo Link](https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490)

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the thickness of the plus sign using some padding/borders too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just adjust according to your needs, and also don't forget to support other browsers for `flex`.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  thumbnail: {
    height: 68,
    width: 68,
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    border: '1px solid #333',
    borderRadius: '50%'
  },
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for react native since border isn't a style property in stylesheets. Also, we can't use string values for borderRadius.

Answer (score 0):

```
import IconFA from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

<View style={{
  position:'relative',
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignItems:'center',
  width:40,
  height:40,
  backgroundColor:'black'
}}>
  <IconFA name='circle-thin' size={40} color='grey'/>
  <IconFA name='plus' size={20} color='white' style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 99}} />  
</View>
```

I am new to ReactNative, but above snippet should work in your case

[Snack Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@sampat/shallow-watermelons)